# for loops for API calls and then inserting into a single data frame in R

Tags: r, api, loops, dataframe

I'm looking to create a large data set from multiple JSON API calls in R.  When I run my code it returns zero errors, however it produces an empty data frame (called all_prices).  This is the code I'm using:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(anytime)
library(xts)
library(quantmod)

response <- fromJSON('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist')
cryptocurrencies <- data.table::rbindlist(response$Data, fill=TRUE)

for (i in 1:10) {

prices  <- fromJSON(paste0("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?
fsym=",as.character(cryptocurrencies[1,5]),
"&tsym=USD&allData=true&e=CCCAGG"))
prices                   <- data.frame(prices$Data)
prices$Symbol            <- rep(cryptocurrencies[1,5],nrow(prices))

all_prices = do.call(rbind, prices)
}
```

I am wanting each interation to be attached to the dataframe via rbind to create a melted dataset.

I think the problem lies in the "do.call" function, however I'm guessing. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
all_prices <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {
  prices <- fromJSON(paste0("https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym=",
                            as.character(cryptocurrencies[i,5]),
                             "&tsym=USD&allData=true&e=CCCAGG"))$Data
  prices$Symbol            <- rep(cryptocurrencies[i,5],nrow(prices))
  all_prices <- rbind(all_prices, prices)
}
```

prices$Data is already a dataframe, and as you had it before you would be over writing "all_prices" over with each iteration. Also you were looping through with "i" but never used it anywhere in the for loop.

Comment: if it was helpful it would be great if you accepted the answer. thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Consider `lapply` to build a list of dataframes, then run `do.call()` or even data.table's `rbindlist` outside of loop:

```
df_list <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
      json  <- fromJSON(paste0("https://min-api.cryptocompare.co/data/histoday?fsym=",
                               as.character(cryptocurrencies[i,5]),
                               "&tsym=USD&allData=true&e=CCCAGG"))

      prices <- data.frame(json$Data)
      prices$Symbol <- rep(cryptocurrencies[i,5], nrow(prices))

      return(prices)
})

all_prices <- base::do.call(rbind, df_list)

all_prices <- data.table::rbindlist(df_list)
```